# Trigger custom script on specific log message

Tags: script, automation, console

I am using [AirServer](https://www.airserver.com) for **Airplay** on my Mac. As far as I know, **AirServer** does not provide an interface to run scripts on specific actions. However, I found a **AirServer** specific message inside the **Console** app whenever a device connects or disconnects to the service. I also tried the following in **Terminal**:

```
log stream | grep "AirServer"
```

I am looking for an efficient way to run a custom script whenever the process **AirServer** spills out a specific message (in my case connect/disconnect).

Comment: You might be able to take a similar approach to mine for Bluetooth described in my [question here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/389501/silence-launchds-service-only-ran-for-x-seconds-pushing-respawn-out-by-x). You can use `WatchPaths` as I did if it writes to its own log file.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not write its own log file. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

AirServer implements a basic AppleScript interface which can tell you if AirServer is in use by calling:
`osascript -e "tell application \"AirServer\" to inUse"`

Another approach is create a basic app which monitors AirServer's notifications using NSDistributedNotificationCenter:
`com.airserverapp.MirroringDidStart, com.airserverapp.MirroringDidStop,
com.airserverapp.AudioDidStart, com.airserverapp.AudioDidStop,
com.airserverapp.VideoDidStart, com.airserverapp.VideoDidStop`

Comment: I tried the first suggestion and it worked in one direction. Meaning, after starting AirServer the script line returns "false". Once a device connects over Airplay, it turns "true". However, that's it, it never goes back. Also after disconnecting from AirServer, nothing happens and only a restart of the application helps.
About the second suggestion, I could imagine, that this works, but I am not familiar with Swift programming. Therefore this will take a bit longer, at least for me.

Comment: I did some further testing. The AppleScript command `tell application "AirServer" to inUse` does only work if you actually run some music. If you only connect and disconnect, the state `inUse` stays `True`. That is still a bit error prone and I will have to look for a fix/workaround.